# Wrong Answer with Recursive Sum Task

Tags: c++, recursion, sequence

I am working on a problem to print all the non-increasing subsequences with sum equal to a given number n, using recursion. I know there is something wrong with my recursive algorithm, but I have walked through the process multiple times and I cannot find my error. With input 4, my code gives output:

4
431
4322
432211
43213
4321321
43213212
4321321211
**I believe the recursion is holding on to previous numbers or sums used in past recursive calls, but cannot find why. Can anybody please help me figure out why the program is not giving correct output?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int n;

void sums(int sum, string str)
{
  if (sum==n)
  {
    cout << str << "\n";
    return;
  }
  for (int i = n-sum; i >= 1; i--)
  {
    str+=to_string(i);
    sums(sum+i, str);
  }
}

int main()
{
  cin >> n;
  string s = "";
  sums(0, s);
}
```

Comment: You add the number to `str`, then hand it to the function. So the first call would have `str = "4"`, then you pass that to `sums`, which would then have `sum = "43"`, etc

Comment: Yes, but the return statement reverts us back to the sum before the loop recursive call.

Comment: what should be the correct output as per your expectation?

Comment: 1 1 1 1   [space]  2 1 1 [space]   2 2   [space]  31  [space]  4

Comment: after first call to sums(0,"") next recursive call would be sums(4, "4") , which will print "4" not 1

Comment: yes, it is just in opposite order...

Comment: I am looking for the issue with my recursion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your: `str+=to_string(i);` inside your for loop.

on the first call you have sum 0, str = "", and in the for loop it goes from i = 4, i--. but inside the body you append to str += 4 and call sums(4, "4"), and the error happens on the next loop i--, str += "3" and becomes "43" and sums(3, "43");

You can fix it by not modifying str, but calling 
`sums(sum + i, str + to_string(i));`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of recursive functions, I believe there should not be a loop at all! so, replace :

```
for (int i = n-sum; i >= 1; i--)
{
  str+=to_string(i);
  sums(sum+i, str);
}
```

by:

```
str+=to_string(n-sum);
sums(n-sum, str);
```